# Issues Over ssh

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, vnc-server

[image: Screenshot]

This is an example how my matlab looks like, any idea what's wrong? I am using it through ssh, with vnc-server it works properly though.

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh9kc.png) to see full-resolution image.

Edit- Also, I am not able to use things which are already installed, but can be used by others. I feel there is something wrong with my environment variables. Can someone tell me how can this be fixed?

Comment: You haven't provided any details. Could you describe in more detail how you're running matlab through ssh? What ssh client are you using? How did you start ssh? How are you running matlab?

Comment: I am just using this command: " ssh -X username@pcname"

Comment: Does this happen with any other programs that have a GUI?  Does this happen only with MATLAB?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't replicate this problem w/ matlab 2014a on centos6.

Comment: @rayryeng This is happening with all others programs with GUI.

Comment: @MojoJojo - Then it's no longer a MATLAB issue but a VNC issue.  You should probably contact the systems administrator who is responsible for the server you are connecting to.  This is something we can't help you fix.

Comment: @rayryeng. It works fine for all other people using MATLAB and other GUI programs with the server, then shouldn't it be a problem on my computer?

Comment: I don't know enough of your setup to reproduce your error.